# How to display a hover in the box element inside fluidRow in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, hover, tooltip

I have a code which has multiple fluidRows and every fluidrow comprises of multiple collapsible box elements which are default collapsed,
my concern is to display a hover when the box is collapsed on the shiny app, depicting "you can open the box to see the data and also a small brief about the data present"

With BSTooltip functionality I am able to show a hover on the data inside the box but not on the collapsible box.

This is a major functionality.

Please help.

```
fluidRow(
                box(
                  id = "djc",
                  title = "BY SEGMENT",
                  width = 12,
                  status = "primary",
                  solidHeader = TRUE,
                  align='center',
                  collapsible = TRUE,
                  collapsed = TRUE,
                  DT::dataTableOutput("tab_PF2")
                ),
                bsTooltip("djc", "This is a Table which talks about all the segments and there data shift and book shift respectfully", placement = "bottom", trigger = "hover",
                          options = NULL)
              ))
```

Above is one fluid row in which I can depict tooltip on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve your question by applying js on columns not on column names.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$mtcarsTable <- DT::renderDataTable({

      DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars[,1:3], 
                    options = list(rowCallback = JS(
                      "function(nRow) {",
                      "var full_text = 'Test1';",
                      "var full_text1 = 'Test2';",
                      "$('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
                      "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text1);",
                      "}")
                    )
      )

    })
  }
)
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your exact use case, but you can use `JavaScript` to add a `title` attribute to all the box collapse buttons.

Add this code to your `ui`:

```
tags$head(tags$script("
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.btn.btn-box-tool').attr('title', 'hovering info');
  });
"))
```